# Using async/await to return the result of a Xamarin.Forms dependency service callback?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms project and implemented a dependency service to send an SMS but I can't figure out how to convert the device independent callbacks into an async await so that I can return it. For example, with my iOS implementation I have something like:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(MySms))]
namespace MyProject.iOS.DS
{
    class MySms : IMySms
    {
        // ...

       public void SendSms(string to = null, string message = null)
        {
            if (MFMessageComposeViewController.CanSendText)
            {
                MFMessageComposeViewController smsController= new MFMessageComposeViewController();
                // ...
                smsController.Finished += SmsController_Finished;
            }
        }
    }
    private void SmsController_Finished(object sender, MFMessageComposeResultEventArgs e)
    {
        // Convert e.Result into my smsResult enumeration type
    }
}
```

I can change `public void SendSms` to `public Task<SmsResult> SendSmsAsyc` but how do I await for the Finished callback and get it's result so that I can have `SendSmsAsync` return it?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Because when I call my SendSms function I need to get the result of the operation back, like:  `var smsResult = await DependencyService.Get<IMySms>().SendSms(to: toSmsNumber, message: smsMessage);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public interface IMySms
{
    Task<bool> SendSms(string to = null, string message = null);
}

public Task<bool> SendSms(string to = null, string message = null)
{
    //Create an instance of TaskCompletionSource, which returns the true/false
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    if (MFMessageComposeViewController.CanSendText)
    {
        MFMessageComposeViewController smsController = new MFMessageComposeViewController();

        // ...Your Code...             

        //This event will set the result = true if sms is Sent based on the value received into e.Result enumeration
        smsController.Finished += (sender, e) =>
        {
             bool result = e.Result == MessageComposeResult.Sent;
             //Set this result into the TaskCompletionSource (tcs) we created above
             tcs.SetResult(result);
        };
    }
    else
    {
        //Device does not support SMS sending so set result = false
        tcs.SetResult(false);
    }
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Call it like:

```
bool smsResult = await DependencyService.Get<IMySms>().SendSms(to: toSmsNumber, message: smsMessage);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing and it worked like a charm. When I asked the question I had no idea TaskCompletionSource even existed. Once I learned what it was I then realized I had to put my Finished event inline as an anonymous function instead of having it as a separate function. I was so busy working on my project I forgot to come back and post the answer.

Comment: What does your android implementation look like?